# Listitem: render HTML instead of escaping it using setLabel or any other method

Tags: java, zk

If I do

```
listitem.setLabel("<p>HTML code</p>");
```

I get an escaped version of it. But how can I render HTML using *setLabel* (or maybe some other method to display content) instead of having it escaped?

Overriding *setLabel* doesn't help as it's only a delegator method and the actual content parsing happens some levels below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this by `setLabel(...)` but by adding a
 `Listcell` and [`Html`](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/HTML_Tags/The_html_Component) Component

```
Listcell c = new Listcell();
Html h = new Html();
h.setContent("MY HTML STRING HERE");
c.appendChild(h);
listitem.appendChild(c);
```